# Zend Framework and PayPal REST cURL session problems

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework, curl, paypal

So I'm doing work updating a charity's webpage that uses Zend Framework.  I've never used it before, but it is pretty much used for everything on the site.  I've been able to figure out most stuff, but this is a bit beyond my abilities.

What they wanted is the ability to have their users (who must login first) select some items from their page and then pay for those items through PayPal.  In order to accomplish this I used the PayPal REST functions with curl in PHP.

The problem is the very first time that the user logs into our site, selects their items, and then gets sent to the paypal page to pay (and then subsequently kicked back to our site) it logs them out of our site.  This causes a bunch of problems, most notably that I can't execute the transaction, so the user thinks they have paid but we won't receive the money.

Weirdly if the user logs back into our page and then tries the same thing again it works perfectly (i.e. doesn't log them out).

In the below code I already have my PayPal token and $data is set correctly (and I cut out some stuff that's not relevant):

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                           "Content-Type: application/json",
                                           "Authorization: Bearer " . $jsontoken->access_token, 
                                           "Content-length: ".strlen($data))
           );                   

$curlresult2 = curl_exec($ch);

foreach ($json_resp['links'] as $link)
{
    if($link['rel'] == 'approval_url')
    {
        $payment_detail_url = $link['href'];
        $payment_detail_method = $link['method'];
    }
}

session_write_close();
$this->_redirect($payment_detail_url);
```

Comment: What is the session lifetime set to? Also garbage collection? Have you moved to another domain name? Is it one type of browser? (I had issues with IE8 and "third party" cookie settings)

Comment: I have no idea what the session lifetime is set to, I'm not familiar with Zend and where these variables are stored.  It happens even if you just logged in and it's always just the first time though.  It happens with all browsers.  I should add that the redirect is moving the user from my domain to the paypal domain and then paypal sends him back.  The weird thing to me is that it works totally fine the second time you login and try... just not the first.

Comment: The session is usually set in bootstrap.php in the application folder and/or configured in config.ini. zend Framework is so flexible that it depends on how it was set up. First step is to track down where the session is configured and set. By default it should only expire when the browser is closed. I have a PayPal payment page and my app works well, no issues with sessions.

Comment: @Gavin    ;;;;;;;;;;
;SESSIONS;
;;;;;;;;;;
resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/sessions"
resources.session.gc_maxlifetime = 18000
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 18000 ..... that was what was in my application.ini.